# query generated by SSAS contains subqueries

Tags: sql-server, ssas, cube

I created a cube that for now consists of a simple partition that looks something like this:

```
select table1.col1, table1.col2, table1.col3 from table1
```

when i examine the query that SSAS is executing using sql profiler the resulting query looks like

```
select [dbo_table1].[col1],[dbo_table1].[col2],[dbo_table1].[col3] from
(
    select table1.col1, table1.col2, table1.col3 from table1
)
```

For some other tables and seemingly similar queries, the resulting query get wrapped twice, with another inner select.  I'm trying to understand why this happens and if there is a way to get the exact query I write to be executed.

The cube is built using `VS 2012 Premium (11.0.3000.0)` and my `SQL Server is 2012 (11.0.3128)`

Comment: Is there something missing from what SSAS is pulling?  That subselect should be what you put in your partition or related to the particular dimension attribute being processed.  The wrapper shouldn't change anything about the query itself, but you would see subsets for dimensions of the original DSV query since it's only looking to get attribute values.

Comment: No, the results returned are all fine but this is only part of the story.  Im actually trying tp build the cube against a non sql db using an oledb driver.  The driver works fine if ssas only wraps once but multiple wrappings create an issue.

Comment: Can you share an example of when it's going deeper than one subselect without that subselect being in your source query?  I believe the behavior is rooted in the data relationships you're bringing into the cube, and it makes me wonder if a really flat cube would perform as you're hoping.